# Installing flask extension: ext = Ext(app) versus Ext(app)

Tags: python, flask

I'm learning flask web development by following a tutorial. Currently, the first few lines of my app is:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_bootstrap import Bootstrap

app = Flask(__name__)

bootstrap = Bootstrap(app)
```

However, when I change `bootstrap = Bootstrap(app)` to `Bootstrap(app)`, nothing breaks. So what's the purpose of storing the `Bootstrap` instance in a variable, which is not used in the rest of code?

Comment: If you're not using it, you're right, there isn't any point. The example usage doesn't suggest you'll need that, either. https://github.com/mbr/flask-bootstrap#usage The tutorial might not be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your current code, it's true there is no need to keep the instance into a variable,

But in practice, you would create the Bootstrap instance without passing the `app` instance, then on some initialization method, you would call the `init_app` method of the Bootstrap instance to initialize it with `app`, like so:

```
bootstrap = Bootstrap()

def create_app(config_name):
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_object(config[config_name])

    bootstrap.init_app(app)

    return app
```

This will also include all other instances of other tools, like Flask-SQLALchemy, Moment, Mail...etc